# How to curve a texture in blender?

Tags: texturing, node-editor

I'm having trouble framing this question, but I'm trying to take this flowing river texture and curve it, so that it looks like it's flowing around a river bend.

Here are the pictures of the texture and the texture nodes. The river is animated by key-framing the x location in the mapping node. I think it would work by key-framing the location and scale values in the mapping node in a certain way. But I don't know how to change the scale based on where the texture is located on the plane. Is there a way to do this?

[image] [image]

Comment: Hello :). Wouldn't it be way easier to just bend the plane?

Comment: So the question is about creating a procedural river shape containing the flow you describe in the question? Could you illustrate it by some additionnal drawings?

Comment: @JachymMichal Could i do this using the bend modifier? I think i would want to bend in around one of the corners

Answer (score 2):

The answer to this was much less complicated than I thought! No need for messing around with the texture nodes.

I just set the origin of the plane to one of the corners, then applied the Simple Deform modifier with bend around the z axis. Here is the output... S/o @JachymMichal for the suggestion

[image]

Comment: Exactly what I had in mind :).

Comment: @JachymMichal Would it be possible to do multiple bends on one plane object, or would it have to be separate planes with single bends stitched together?

Comment: Hey :). You mean shape it like a river? You could use a curve modifier for that